# Insert em tabela - valor estranho

Tags: java, html, angularjs

Estou tentando inserir um valor em uma tabela a partir de um select option.

html:

```
<select class="form-control" name="chaveCadastro" ng-options="cadastro.cadastroId for cadastro in (cadastro | orderBy:'id' | filter:{active:true}) track by cadastro.id" ng-model="cad.cadGeral.chaveCadastro"  id="cadastro">
</select>
```

angular:

```
cadGeral = result.data.value;

console.log(cad.cadGeral.chaveCadastro.id);
```

java:

```
public class cadGeral extends IdentityObject { 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
    @Column(name = "fk_cadastro") 
    public Cadastro chaveCadastro;
```

No console.log vem correto.

No insert, o campo está indo com um valor nada a ver tipo sempre o mesmo: 1864385090. Suspeito que esteja tentando inserir o objeto todo e não o valor que quero, o id.

No html não consigo fazer por exempo `ng-model="cad.cadGeral.chaveCadastro.id"`
que dá erro não reconhece o id.

Como faço para à partir deste objeto chaveCadastro pegar somente o id no html e não o objeto todo?

Comment: Onde entra JAVA nesse problema?

Comment: public class cadGeral extends IdentityObject {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 
 @Column(name = "fk_cadastro")
 public Cadastro chaveCadastro;

Comment: aqui que trato a tabela no java

Comment: Só uma dica. As classes em Java são sempre iniciadas com letras maiúscula!

Comment: Dica, procure formatar o código ao adicionar, não cole de qualquer jeito na pergunta, isso atrapalha a leitura da pergunta e de quem for te ajudar. Lembre-se sempre de facilitar a vida de quem for te ajudar, fornecendo uma pergunta clara e bem formatada, assim a chance de obter respostas.